# Burden of proof at customs

Tags: criminal-law

I am not a law professional at all but I all of a sudden realized something to which I cannot find a reasonable answer. In customs (or in similar law-enforcement acts), why is the burden of proof on the subject but not on the state?

CASE 1) If Acme Inc. imports some agricultural products, then she needs to demonstrate that everything complies with the biosafety regulations rather than the officers proving a violation. Then Acme needs to perform any necessary test by herself.

CASE 2) If it is claimed Mrs. X is insane and needs a guardian, then the burden of proof is with the plaintiff. Mrs. X need not prove that she is a reasonable person to a public authority every single minute to remain officially sane.

My interpretation for the case 2 is that somebody is assumed to be reasonable by nature unless something happens. But why is some"thing" is not OK by default?

Comment: What's the country?

Comment: What does case 2 have to do with customs?

Comment: @GabrielDiego Say US. I do not know whether the country matters. Is not such a thing universal.

Comment: @phoog Well, let me then modify like this. Mrs. X can simply fill a declaration at customs, without she needing to prove that she is sane.

Comment: The is no universal law, even international treaties need to be ratified (voted in parliament or whatever applies) in each of the respective countries signing it. It really depends on the laws of the country where the situation is happening. If the product in already in a United States port, so it is subject to the US law. The answers given below give a excellent explanation in more details for the case of United States.

Comment: @GabrielDiego My answer was deliberately worded to apply to any country that maintains presumption of innocense in criminal prosecutions.  The US is far from alone in that.

Comment: As I told you, it still depends on the local law. The "presumption of innocence" is just a abstract term and each country implements it own way through their laws. It is not like 2 + 2 = 4. Laws are a human science and they not necessarily the way you think it should be and you are not the only one to think like that. I agree with you that some laws or regulations boils down to some common aspects in most of the world, but those subjects are too broad to discuss here, so it is better to narrow your jurisdiction to have a quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of the burden of proof in a criminal prosecution, which rests with the prosecution because defendants are presumed innocent.

The cases you describe are not criminal prosecutions, so different rules prevail.

Answer (score 1):

Using the United States and your case 1 that Acme has to demonstrate their imported products comply with U.S. law rather than the border patrol having to prove they don't:

No one is charged with a crime here so there is nothing the government has to prove.

However, Section 8 of Article I of the U.S. Constitution grants to The Congress the power:

> To regulate commerce with foreign nations, and among the several states, and with the Indian tribes;

Therefore, in regulating commerce with foreign nations, Congress can pass a law that says that importers of products must demonstrate that their products comply with U.S. law.

Comment: I think I see now the principle. Owner of something can impose any policy regulating on access to it, you are free (not to) comply. If the owner charges for a violation, then s/he needs to prove.